# JUnit5 and IntelliJ IDEA: Kotlin function naming with backticks and brackets

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, junit, jetbrains-ide

After upgrade from **JUnit 4** to **JUnit 5** and upgrade from `org.junit.Test` to `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` test call stops working if you directly run test methods via **IntelliJ IDEA** (running test by class works fine) for tests with brackets and backticks in Kotlin.

**The workaround is to remove brackets from test names.** See Kotlin examples below.

JUnit 4:

```
import org.junit.Test

class A {
    @Test
    fun `my (fun)` (){
    }
}
```

works fine when you run this method from Idea directly

JUnit 5:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class A {
    @Test
    fun `my (fun)` (){
    }
}
```

fails with exception due to braces "()" in the name:

```
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:189)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:168)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: MethodSelector [className = 'dsf.A', methodName = 'my ', methodParameterTypes = 'fun'] resolution failed
```

I understand that an issue happens because API in JUnit changed and now IntelliJ passes parameters with brackets that are parsed to some new JUnitApi arguments.

But can someone help to understand the deep root of this problem. Is it a functional bug in Idea or it is a bug in JUnit?

PS Buggy Bonus:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a Junit problem. Try prepending `@JvmName("myFun")` to the function and see if that works

Comment: @smac89, yes of course this works fine - this is same to changing the name to "fun myFun"

Comment: @smac89 I guess that the issue comes from Intellij

Comment: ‘Braces’ usually refers to `{` `}`; `(` `)` are usually ‘brackets’, ‘round brackets’, ‘parentheses’ or ‘parens’.  (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Names_for_various_bracket_symbols).)

Comment: I don't think it's an IntelliJ issue, because I just had this work on my intelliJ. Are you using gradle by any chance? [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/L9fQx7d.png)

Comment: @smac89 reproduced this issue with all of my colleagues :) We are using maven and different versions of idea - I am using 2019, others are using 2020 - same issue

Comment: Try filing bug reports against both [IJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue) and [Junit](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/new/choose) and see where that leads.

Comment: I notice your screenshot has `package dsf` underlined as if to warn about something. Maybe you can start with that. I don't know if that will lead anywhere seeing as you said everyone else on your team has the same issue, but do file the bug reports as suggested by @Egor and see if that reveals the issue